# Linux process execution history

Tags: linux

I have a multi-threaded (three threads) application in Linux 3.4.0 with RT7 (realtime) patch. The application needs realtime execution with ~20ms tolerance.The application runs for a while (1 min to 50min) with realtime then I find that while one of the threads is doing some processing, a context switch happens and it comes back to the thread about 80 to 500ms later. I need to find out what process takes away the time slice. All my threads together consume ~5% CPU time. Is there any tool to see process execution history with time stamp?

Thanks,
Hakim

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/). It is dynamic instrumentation engine inspired by DTrace. It dynamically patches kernel (so it will need debuginformation for it).

For example, your task may be achieved with this script:

```
probe scheduler.cpu_on, scheduler.cpu_off {
    if(pid() == target()) {
        printf("%ld %s\n", gettimeofday_us(), pn());
    }
}
```

Use `-c` option to attach this script to a command or `-x` to a running PID:

```
root@lkdevel:~# stap  -c 'dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null count=1' ./schedtrace.stp
...
1423701880670656 scheduler.cpu_on
1423701880673498 scheduler.cpu_off
1423701880674208 scheduler.cpu_on
1423701880689407 scheduler.cpu_off
1423701880689829 scheduler.cpu_on
...
```

Comment: Yes, this tool will help, thanks a lot. I tried to run your script but -p options did not work. I may be able to find out the reason after learning how to write this kind of script, until then if you have any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: @user3338393 What do mean "did not work": `stap` printed some error, no output was provided, etc.? It is also useful to add `-v` to `stap` command line, so some debug output will come.

Comment: it does not run, it says "Invalid pass number (should be 1-5)."

Comment: @user3338393, ooh, I'm so sorry, always confuse it with DTrace. The correct option is `-x`

Comment: Yes, this works. Is it possible to put the output into memory then when I do ctrl-c then it'll display all?

Comment: @user3338393, why not redirect output to a file on tmpfs: `stap -o /tmp/output.trs ...` and after you finished, `less /tmp/output.trs`? Saving it in memory is very bad idea (but probably achievable via speculations).